# DBus object error

Tags: python, linux, dbus, opensuse

I'm trying to make a script to launch my custom script when my usb stick connected.
I found nice python script [here](https://superuser.com/questions/22766/automatically-copy-files-to-usb-drive-when-connected/38044#38044) but when it calls **GetAllProperties()** method I get an exception:

> ERROR:dbus.connection:Exception in handler for D-Bus signal: 
> Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   
> File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 214, in
>   maybe_handle_message 
>       self._handler(*args, **kwargs)   
> File "./hal-automount", line 31, in device_added
>      
>  properties = self.udi_to_device(udi).GetAllProperties()
>      
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 68, in
>   __call__
>       return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)   
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 140, in
>   __call__
>       **keywords)   
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 630, in
>   call_blocking
>       message, timeout) 
> DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 3
>   matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.39539" (uid=0 pid=9527
>   comm="python) interface="(unset)" member="getAllProperties" error
>   name="(unset)" requested_reply=0 destination=":1.8" (uid=0 pid=3039
>   comm="/usr/sbin/hald))

OS: openSuSE 11.4

I didn't work with DBus before, can you give me a hint what's wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DBus method call failed due to access policy. It is probably because you called a method without specifying any interface. Looks like a bug in the script you tried to use (DBus methods should always be called via an interface).

Try replacing:

```
def udi_to_device(self, udi):
    return self.bus.get_object("org.freedesktop.Hal", udi)
```

With:

```
def udi_to_device(self, udi):
    obj = self.bus.get_object("org.freedesktop.Hal", udi)
    return dbus.Interface(obj, dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.Hal.Device')
```

BTW: HAL is now obsolete, you should probably switch to udisks. See http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/hal

Comment: This looks related to my question - could you check it out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424037/dbus-to-python-takes-exactly-1-argument