# Get 'state' from dbus using python

Tags: python, dbus, firewalld

I want to do a very simple thing in python - read the state from firewalld over dbus - "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" .

According to https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewalld.dbus.html

```
state - s - (ro)
firewalld state. This can be either INIT or RUNNING. In INIT state, firewalld is starting up and initializing.
```

I found how to do it with dbus-send from linux, but I just can't get it right in python.

Here's the closest SO answer to my question, but I still can't figure it out.
[[dbus_to_python() takes exactly 1 argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424037/dbus-to-python-takes-exactly-1-argument])

```
Here's how to do it in shell:
firewall-cmd --state
running 

And with dbus-send:
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1 /org/fedoraproject/FirewallD1 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:"org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1" string:"state"
method return time=1563593597.133270 sender=:1.2 -> destination=:1.116 serial=691 reply_serial=2
   variant       string "RUNNING"
```

```
# Here's my incorrect code:
import dbus
Bus = dbus.SystemBus()
Proxy = Bus.get_object('org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1', '/org/fedoraproject/FirewallD1')
Proxy.Get('state', dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')
```

And here's the error message I get from python:

```
ERROR:dbus.connection:Unable to set arguments ('state',) according to signature 'ss': <class 'TypeError'>: More items found in D-Bus signature than in Python arguments
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 641, in call_blocking
    message.append(signature=signature, *args)
TypeError: More items found in D-Bus signature than in Python arguments
>>>
```

Comment: Here's the solution:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `Get` method of the `org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties` interface actually takes two arguments the interface to access the property of and the name of that property:

```
org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get (in STRING interface_name,
                                     in STRING property_name,
                                     out VARIANT value);
```

From https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#standard-interfaces-properties

```
import dbus
Bus = dbus.SystemBus()
Proxy = Bus.get_object('org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1', '/org/fedoraproject/FirewallD1')
Proxy.Get('org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1', 'state', dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')
```

Tested with different constants as I don't have that specific DBus service or object.

Comment: Thanks for that. I eventually figured this out and posted the answer precisely at the same time you posted your response.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```
Proxy.Get('org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1', 'state', dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')
```